# How to access the Webform Mysql View

Tags: 7, webforms

I enabled the module Webform Mysql Views (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views). Enabled the webform for which I want to create the view through here - http://YOURWEBSITE/admin/content/webform/mysql

I am still unsure how can I actually see my view in this case. Where do I find it? I was expecting it under the results section just in case but I am unable to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is probably not timely to pal4life, but for anyone else still looking for answers.... this view doesn't show up via the Views module per say.  It is best used in conjunction with other modules or code.

For example, I wanted to get filtering functionality on my Webform views and using the Webform MySQL View module seemed to be the recommended way to go.  However, you will most likely need to install the Data and Schema modules as well.  A great walk through on how to use all three together to create filterable, sortable webform data via Views can be found here:

http://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/displaying-webform-submission-data-drupal-views#comment-1085